# Is there a tool for A/B audio-comparison?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, music, music-player, audio-player

I've been in this situation a few times where I would like to directly comare two audio files sonically to each other.

Maybe to decide on a different mix or to compare "full dynamic range" versions with the original CD tracks.

Is there a program that can play back two comparable audio files at the same time and switch the output from one to the other at the click of a button or a key, so that the sound continues at the same point on the other file without pausing or having to open another player instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`abx`, available in the Ubuntu software repositories, is designed to perform audio ABX testing. It allows you to determine if you can discern audible differences between two samples.

Comment: Hi, thanks. That seems like a nifty tool for this purpose. Unfortunately, I can't play my samples since I always get the error "can't initialize playback". You don't happen to know how to fix that?